# Загрузка текста с определенного места

Tags: python, tkinter

Виджет Tkinter.Text. Можно ли сделать, чтобы текст выводился на экран с определенного места? Ну то есть я создаю виджет, передаю ему какой-то текст, но хочу, чтобы он открылся на определенном месте (с середины, например). Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-разному. Например так:

```
from Tkinter import *
r = Tk()
t = Text(r, heigh=10, width=30)
t.grid(row=0, column=0)
sx = Scrollbar(r, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=t.xview)
sy = Scrollbar(r, orient=VERTICAL, command=t.yview)
sx.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
sy.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
t['yscrollcommand'] = sy.set
t['xscrollcommand'] = sx.set
f = open('b.txt')
lines = 0
try:
    for line in f:
        t.insert(END, line)
        lines = lines + 1
finally:
    f.close()
t.see('%d.0' % (lines/2))
r.mainloop()
```

Comment: И что это?????? Один символ в виджете текст...... Я совсем не то имел ввиду.

Comment: Вы об чём? Один символ -- это откуда? У меня в файле b.txt 36 строк. А указать я хотел именно на метод .see